# has_and_belongs_to_many query works in one direction, fails in the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :staffs
```

and

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
```

With the intermediate table services_staffs with columns services_id and staffs_id

The following query succeeds:

```
Staff.find( :all, :conditions => "service_id = #{service_id}" )
```

But going the other direction fails:

```
Service.find( :all, :conditions => "staff_id = #{staff_id}" )
```

with

Service Load (0.3ms)   SELECT "services".*, t0.staff_id as the_parent_record_id FROM "services" INNER JOIN "services_staffs" t0 ON "services".id = t0.service_id WHERE (t0.staff_id IN (12,13,14))    Service Load (0.0ms)   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: staff_id: SELECT * FROM "services" WHERE (staff_id = 13)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: staff_id: SELECT * FROM "services" WHERE (staff_id = 13) ):

Any idea why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally use has_many and then through, but the concept is the same.  You need to include the association in the search so either

```
Service.find( :all, :include => :staffs, :conditions => "staffs.id = #{staff_id}" )
```

This will do an outer join so will include all services and will eager load the staff data.

```
Service.find( :all, :joins => :staffs, :conditions => "staffs.id = #{staff_id}" )
```

This will do an inner join and only have the service datasets (it will have to go to the database if you call `service.staffs`

for unsolicited advice, I recommend modifying your query a bit.

```
Service.all(:include => :staffs, :conditions => ["staffs.id = ?", staff_id])
```

The array escapes your `staff_id` variable to help to prevent malicious code attacks.

Comment: arg, my fault... it should have been `staffs.staff_id` not `services.staff_id`

Comment: Awesome, got it! Thanks again. In my case it was actually "staffs.id = ?".